# How to get the address of the code being executed from CALLCODE?

Tags: solidity, callcode

I want to write a library which can be callcalled by any contract.

As part of this, I want to write a function which returns the contract address of the library to the contract which callcalled it.

`address(this)` is normally the solution, but in the case of callcode, it can only be used to check if the contract is being callcalled through  `if(address(this)==msg.sender)` which become always true.

So how to perform this without having to rewrite the code each time because of the requirement to predict the future library’s contract address ?